# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jqzoom'

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, jqzoom

I'm getting this error in browser console.
I'm working on a `magento` website where on the product view page I've to use `jqzoom`.

What I've done far is:

1. Added jquery
2. Added jqzoom library
3. Added my custom js

[image: screenshot]

The code in `product-view-config.js` is

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('.more-views > ul').bxSlider({
        mode: 'vertical',
        slideMargin: 15,
        pager: false,
        minSlides: 4,
        infiniteLoop: false
    });
    $j('a#pz').jqzoom();
});
```

In this case, `bxSlider` working well but `jqzoom` not working.

[image: console output]

---

**EDIT**

I'd figured out why `jqzoom` not working and added in my answer. But why `jqzoom` is not working with `jquery 1.10`?

Comment: This type of errors, don't think anybody can help, nor it helps anybody else. How does the stack trace look like? Any clues there?

Comment: what stach trace? Does the console output in browser?

Comment: Apparently `bxslider` is a different plugin than `jqzoom`. Are you sure both were loaded? Are you sure both are working with your prototypejs-conflicts?

Comment: As I can see, both are loaded in `<head>` and accessible in view source. Also, `bxSlider` working fine on the product page. `Are you sure both are working with your prototypejs-conflicts?` - I've no idea about it

Comment: I'm using `jquery-1.10` does that can cause a problem for `jqzoom`? http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/ - there, they have used `jquery-1.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This type of errors, don't think anybody can help, nor it helps
>   anybody else. How does the stack trace look like? Any clues there? – 
>   elclanrs

You were right. [Q-Zoom Extension for magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/q-zoom.html) help me to resolve this problem

---

Moreover, I'd found that I was using `jquery 1.10` and [the above Q-Zoom extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/q-zoom.html) using `jquery 1.6`. If I remove the extension's `jquery 1.6` it again stop working.